# Is there a easy way to rename a table in procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I am using MariaDB 10.1 SQLyog 11.5

I've renamed the table using below query.

```
ALTER TABLE old_name RENAME new_name
```

But there are many stored procedures that reference 'old_name'. I've opened all the SP creation query and changed. Because I don't know which SP has a query that reference old_name table.

Is there a way to know which SP has queries that reference old_name table?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT O.[name] FROM SysObjects O JOIN SysComments C ON C.Id = O.Id WHERE C.[text] LIKE '%old_name%'` this is working in MSSQL. For MySQL you can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.` related tables, this is not the solution but may give some idea to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By this [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/routines-table.html) you can fetch the text available in the stored procedure

Please could try this query: *(not verified)*

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%old_name%'
      -- AND ROUTINE_TYPE = "PROCEDURE" -- Filter only if need SPs
ORDER BY ROUTINE_NAME;
```

Reference from this [page](http://www.shayanderson.com/mysql/query-for-finding-text-in-mysql-stored-procedure.htm)

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I want! "You can fetch the text available in the stored procedure" is also a great hint. Thank you Arulmumar!!

Answer (score 0):

You can it do like this:

**Create RENAME Query**

```
SELECT  CONCAT ('RENAME TABLE ',
  GROUP_CONCAT(t.TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',t.TABLE_NAME,' TO ', t.TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',REPLACE(t.TABLE_NAME,'old','NEW') SEPARATOR ' , ') 
) INTO @sql
FROM information_schema.TABLES t
WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('SCHEMA1','SCHEMA2')
AND t.TABLE_NAME LIKE 'old_table%';
```

**ONLY to verify**

```
SELECT @sql;
```

**Prepare and execute it**

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: What I want is a list of SP that contains query which references the 'old_name' table. But you guided me a new way to make a RENAME TABLE sentences. Thank you.